# A href inside my own tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I created my own tooltip, is 1 fullscreen `div.over-bg` and 1 little div on the middle of screen `div.over-box`:

```
<div class="over-bg" id="over-hat">
    <div class="over-box">        
        <a href="">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS to make it showing and hiding:

```
    $('.over-bg').click(function(){
       $('.over-bg').fadeOut();//hidding when we click outside .over-box
    });

    $('#over-hat .over-box').click(function(){
        return false;// do nothing when we click into .over-box
    });
```

Everything works perfect, but when I have a link inside `div.over-box`, it doesn't work. I want to make, tooltip closes only when we click outside that. But links have to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your link has no `href` attribute, so clicking it would have no effect - assuming your HTML example is not trucated.

Comment: Have any CSS? Please paste it

Comment: I believe if you set the zindex of over-box to be higher than over-bg click functions wont be called.

Comment: Code provided is not what OP has stated as 'everything works perfect' Please post your entire sample code on jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second code snippet to the following:

```
$('#over-hat .over-box').click(function(e){
   return($(e.target).prop("tagName")=="A");
});
```

This will help the `a` tag to go with its default action and others to ignore the event.

Comment: @Zaszczyk - you could use this suggestion and simply modify the return statement to test for all cases where you might need to click (ie: buttons, links, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this JQuery statement in addition to what you already have:

```
$('#over-hat .over-box a').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: This is not bad solution, but I need something universal for buttons and tags with ID, which will start AJAX etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just assuming here, but it sounds like you want `.over-bg` to fadeOut when you click the link. If so, you'll have to set up another click handler for the anchor itself, because I think the default behavior for anchors is to not bubble their event up.

Take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TCegn/